# Execute query in python

Tags: python, mysql

I have a simple table

```
******************
MId  |  Title
1    |  pqr
2    |  abc
******************
```

now the code which i have written to append data to table is

```
 import MySQLdb
 db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "a", "Project")
 cursor = db.cursor()
 sql = "INSERT INTO Project.Movie(MId, Title) VALUES(%d, %s)" % (21,'aman') 
 cursor.execute(sql)
```

But the above code generates error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 159, in execute
    query = query % db.literal(args)
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str
```

I have just passed number and not in quotes then why is there an error ?

Comment: Regardless of the answers below, formatting the SQL on the python side is a bad practice due to SQL injection.  Look at [how the official docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) pass parameters into `execute()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your real issue here is quite simply not putting quotes around your inserted string. As [Izkata](https://stackoverflow.com/users/500202/izkata) remarked, you really shouldn't be doing this Python-side wise due to SQL injection. 
Were this SQL-side, your entire query must be in a string format when being executed, thus you must use `%s` for every field.

Your string *(instead of `%d`)* will be converted into an SQL literal value in any case upon executing your query.

In your case, you should be writing your insertion statement like this (as seen in the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html)):

```
sql = (
  "INSERT INTO Project.Movie (MId, Title) "
  "VALUES (%s, %s)"
)
data = (21,'aman')
cursor.execute(sql, data)
```

Answer (score 2):

Also you want quotes around your string value:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO Project.Movie(MId, Title) VALUES(%s, '%s')" % ('21','aman')
```